# Re-evaluate a ListView's SelectedItem after changing ItemSource

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, selecteditem

I have a `ListView` which I would like te re-evaluate its `SelectedItem` once it receives a new `ItemSource`. The goal of this is to 'remember' if the user already selected an item in the `ListView`.

XAML:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="_matchingTvShowsFromOnlineDatabaseListView" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="3"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableMatchingTvShows}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding AcceptedMatchingTvShow, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The `SelectedItem` is also bound to a property on my VM.

The VM:

```
public IWebApiTvShow AcceptedMatchingTvShow
{
    get
    {
        IWebApiTvShow acceptedTvShow = null;
        if (FoundTvShows.Count > 0)
        {
            var tvShowName = FoundTvShows[CurrentTvShow];
            acceptedTvShow = AvailableTvShowMatches[tvShowName].FirstOrDefault(webApiTvShow => webApiTvShow.Accepted);
        }
        return acceptedTvShow;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var tvShowName = FoundTvShows[CurrentTvShow];
            var currentlyAcceptedTvShow =
                AvailableTvShowMatches[tvShowName].FirstOrDefault(webApiTvShow => webApiTvShow.Accepted);
            if (currentlyAcceptedTvShow != null)
            {
                currentlyAcceptedTvShow.Accepted = false;
            }
            value.Accepted = true;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I made a screen shot of the application I am building, which hopefully makes clear what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

The idea would be that when the user is navigating through the TV Shows, the application would remember the associated TV Show.

Currently, when I associate a TV Show, and navigate to the next TV Show and back again, nothing is selected (the getter of the property `AcceptedMatchingTvShow` is not executed after setting the new `ItemSource`)

UPDATE:

Added the code for `AvailableMatchingTvShows`

```
private ObservableCollection<IWebApiTvShow> _availableMatchingTvShows;
public ObservableCollection<IWebApiTvShow> AvailableMatchingTvShows
{
    get { return _availableMatchingTvShows; } 
    set
    {
        _availableMatchingTvShows = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AcceptedMatchingTvShow");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to post the Code related to `AvailableMatchingTvShows`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of your ViewModel, I'm guessing if you raise PropertyChanged("AcceptedMatchingTvShow") when the ItemsSource binding changes that would update the SelectedItem binding.

Comment: Right! Sometimes the solution can be so simple. Many thanks!!